# Add constraints with visual format doesn't work (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, visual-format-language

I'm trying to add simple red view on my UITableViewController by adding constraints with visual format. Here is my code (calling in viewDidLoad):

```
private func setupMenuBar() {

    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(myView)

    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: myView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: myView)
```

Here is my extension to UIView class:

```
extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
```

Works fine on my another empty testViewController:UIViewController without any subviews.
As you can see on the picture, here's no any red views:
[App hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM5ur.png)

And at the end of the function i have zero frame:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwlxA.png)

Comment: Have you tried in View Controller not in Table View Controller? Because table owns the view of the view controller in Table View Controller.

Comment: @Mr.Bista As i said, on UIViewController it works fine. But i need to do this on UITableViewController. I was trying to add as subview to tableView and then tableView.addConstraintWithFormat, but nothing happened.

Comment: As i said, `table owns the view of the view controller in Table View Controller` :), hence view can't be added IMO.

Comment: First, make sure you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false in any programmatically created view. Second, tableviewcontroller isn't generally wiporth the trouble; just add a tableview to a viewcontroller and get much more flexibility with layout